# How do I activate my contracts in TF2?

Tags: team-fortress-2

I went to the right map and killed somebody but it did nothing but give me souls for my gargoyle. I tried to press <kbd>f2</kbd> and click on the contracts but it did nothing.  I have the halloween `2fort` and another halloween map.

Comment: Do you mind explaining what's going on? What contract do you have? What do you mean by 'it did nothing'?

Comment: @texenox sounds like Halloween content to me. Haven't had a look though.

Comment: You're probably playing on a non-official/non-VAC server. Contracts can only be earned on registered VAC-secure servers IIRC

Comment: @Felix You're better off using your own account to edit your own question, as opposed to creating a new one to do so.

Answer (score 3):

While you do have to be on those maps, you also need to make sure that you're playing this map on an **official Valve-hosted server**. Any other server that isn't hosted by Valve will not allow you to score any contract points.

You also need to make sure that the server you're playing on, even if it's a Valve server on the right map, has 2 or more players on it. If you're by yourself, <s>you can't really do much</s> it's pretty easy to cheat your way through contracts.

[image: Contract activation criteria]

Comment: The '2 or more players' thing is to stop people from just farming the 'environmental' style challenges, like 'cap a point' or 'win a round' etc just to earn the bonuses

Answer (score 1):

You have to be on the correct map to do the contract. Valve has added a button to the contracts that you can click that will automatically take you to the correct map type to complete that contract. Just press F2, select the contract you want to complete, and the button should be on the top left corner of the contract in red text.